# parsing python file with re

Tags: python, regex

I have a python file as

```
test.py 

import os
class test():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def add(num1, num2):
        return num1+num2
```

I am reading this file in a string as :

```
with open('test.py', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

print data
```

Now, my data contains the string with all lines and new lines.
I need to find lines with start of class and def.

for example:

I need the output to be printed as :

```
class test():
def __init__(self):
def add(num1, num2):
```

How can I process this using regular expressions?

Comment: What do you mean `process`?

Comment: I need to process the string data to get the output as shown

Comment: @GáborErdős I believe he means Regex.
OP: What's your motivation?

Comment: I can parse the file line by line but its not an efficient way. Its better that I will get the data in a string and will use regex on it to find the lines.

Comment: @sam Regex is usually slower than some minor logic. Also my question still stands: What's your motivation?

Comment: This python file is small. I ay have bigger files. Plus, it may be possible that my search will first look for class lines, at another times it may look for functions, etc. so its better to keep it in one string than reading the file again and again.

Comment: Basically you need to find all the lines that are either `def` or `class` lines?

Comment: My educated guess is that pyc reflection would be valid, very fast, grouped and way more feature rich.

Comment: Unrelated, but your `add` function does not work. First argument `num1` will be `self`.

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'(?m)^[ \t]*((?:class|def) .*)', data)`. [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xY8qU4/1).

Comment: use the `ast` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to follow a regex approach, use

```
re.findall(r'(?m)^[ \t]*((?:class|def)[ \t].*)', data)
```

or

```
re.findall(r'^[ \t]*((?:class|def)[ \t].*)', data, flags=re.M)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xY8qU4/2)

The point is that you should use `^` as the beginning of the *line* anchor (hence, `(?m)` at the start or `re.M` flag are necessary), then you match horizontal whitespaces (with `[ \t]`), then either `class` or `def` (with `(?:class|def)`), and then again a space or tab and then 0+ chars other than a newline (`.*`).

If you plan to also handle Unicode whitespace, you need to replace `[ \t]` with `[^\S\r\n\f\v]` (and use the `re.UNICODE` flag).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/LMu5zK):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^[ \t]*((?:class|def)[ \t].*)', re.MULTILINE)
s = "test.py \n\nimport os\nclass test():\n\n    def __init__(self):\n        pass\n\n    def add(num1, num2):\n        return num1+num2"
print(p.findall(s))
# => ['class test():', 'def __init__(self):', 'def add(num1, num2):']
```

Comment: Can't you just use `\s` for the whitespaces?

Comment: No, `\s` matches a newline, but `data` is the whole file containing newlines as well. Perhaps, it is ok, but I do not have more input data to test it out.

Comment: Well, I think you could use `\s+?` for non-greedy match and `^...$` to restrict it to one line.

Comment: The `$` is redundant since `.*` *will* match up to the line end. The `^` *is used* in my pattern. As for lazy quantifier with `\s`, there is really no need of it at all, it can be greedy.

Answer (score 2):

So if you need to find all `def` and `class` lines it is much easier to avoid regex.

You read the whole content of the file here

```
with open('test.py', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

print data
```

Why don't you just find the answer right there?

```
with open('test.py', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        stripped = line.strip()  # get rid of spaces left and right
        if stripped.startswith('def') or stripped.startswith('class'):
             print(line)
```

To work with a whole string as you requested:

```
import re
with open('test.py', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()

print(data)

print(re.findall("class.+\n|def.+\n",data))
```

As you can see from the comments this will match ''definied as bla bla' as well. So it is better to use

```
print(re.findall("class .+\n|def .+\n",data))
```

Comment: I dont want to search line by line. My intention is to search inside a complete string of file.

Comment: @sam I'm sorry, but this is exactly what it is doing. Reads a file, rolls through it, yields the results you're searching for.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `line.strip().startswith`?

Comment: what if again in any more loop, I have to search something from file? That time again  I need to open the file and read it again

Comment: @sam You don't need to read it again. You just need to iterate through the lines in the file again. You can use `file.readlines()` if you really want to keep it all in memory.

Comment: @sam I also added a version with regex from a full string if you really what that

Comment: The `"class.+\n|def.+\n"` regex will match `defined here` in `s = "sometext" // s defined here\n` ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZ7tO1/1)) and `"class .+\n|def .+\n"` will find `def here` in `s = "sometext" // my cool def here\n` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZ7tO1/2)).

Comment: 1) You can use `startswith(("def", "class"))`, 2) You should add a space behind both; 3) same for regex, and it does not even check whether it's at the start of the line.

Comment: @GáborErdős having the extra \n in your pattern is redundant because `.` matches everything *except* newlines/line-breaks

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('test.py', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().split('\n')
    for line in data:
        if re.search("(\s+)?class ", line) or re.search("^\s+def ", line):
            print line
```